# Plink is not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, putty, plink

I have batch script which contains *plink* to load the existing putty session and run few commands on *unix* server. The same batch script is running fine from *windows* command line but when I am running it from Jenkins, it is not working and giving the below output.

```
PuTTY Link: command-line connection utility
Release 0.70
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command] ("host" can also be a 
PuTTY saved session name)
Options:
-v        show verbose messages
-load sessname  Load settings from saved session
 -ssh -telnet -rlogin -raw force use of a particular protocol (default 
SSH)
-P port   connect to specified port
-l user   connect with specified username
-m file   read remote command(s) from file
-batch    disable all interactive prompts
The following options only apply to SSH connections:
-pw passw login with specified password
-L listen-port:host:port   Forward local port to remote address
-R listen-port:host:port   Forward remote port to local address
-X -x     enable / disable X11 forwarding
-A -a     enable / disable agent forwarding
-t -T     enable / disable pty allocation
-1 -2     force use of particular protocol version
-C        enable compression
-i key    private key file for authentication
```

Comment: i am using the below command inside the batch script which is able to run from windows command line and execute the unix commands inside command.txt on the unix machine. But while running the batch script from jenkins as command line argument it is giving me the output i mentioned above                                                         
>plink.exe -load "SavedSession" -l "username" -pw "password" -t -m command.txt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by running the commands that are stored in the sessions. For example, instead of running:

```sh
plink -load my-session
```

I instead used

```sh
plink -serial \\.\COM9 -sercfg 115200,8,1,N,N
```

Since sessions are saved in Windows Registry per user, I don't think Jenkins has access to them.